# Multiple file upload and preview (Images and Videos)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a child component that has an input field that is hidden behind a slotted element. The parent will provide the slotted click event element, but also show a preview of the file(s), with the ability to delete them above.

I'm not sure how to work this select and preview functionality when working between a child/parent relationship.

What I have below is as far as I got, but I'm just confused at this point as to where to go.

The slot works to trigger the event in the child, but I get a `"TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."` when trying to actually get things to render as currently written.
Where am I going wrong with this?

If you need anymore information please let me know! Cheer!

**NOTE:** I also need to make this compatitible with V-model, but I don't know how to do that currently.

**UploadMediaFiles** (Child Component)

```
<template>
  <div class="upload-media-files">
    <input
      id="input-file"
      type="file"
      accept="*"
      multiple
      @change="addMedia"
      class="_add-media-input"
      ref="input"
    />
    <label for="input-file">
      <slot :openFileDialog="openFileDialog">
        <img
          src="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/142-1422132_png-file-svg-upload-file-icon-png.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </slot>
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
input
  display: none
</style>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UploadMediaFiles',
  props: {
    multiple: { type: Boolean },
    accept: { type: String },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      files: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    async addMedia(event) {
      const files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files
      if (!files.length) return
      console.log(`files → `, files)
      this.files.push(files)
      this.$emit('selected', this.files)
    },

    openFileDialog() {
      this.$refs.input.click()
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**SelectAndPreviewFiles** (Parent Component)

```
<template>
  <div class="select-and-preview-files">
    <div v-if="selectedFiles">
      <div :key="index" v-for="(selectedFile, index) in selectedFiles">
        <img :src="selectedFile" alt="" />
        <button @click="deleteFile(index)">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- <img />
      //OR
      <video /> -->
    <!-- <img :src="selectedFile" alt="" />-->
    <UploadMediaFiles @selected="(files) => selectFiles(files)" v-slot="{ openFileDialog }">
      <button @click="openFileDialog">
        <img
          src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a1/Circle-icons-upload.svg/1200px-Circle-icons-upload.svg.png"
          alt=""
        />
      </button>
    </UploadMediaFiles>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="sass" scoped>
img
  width: 20%
  margin: auto
  display: block
  margin-bottom: 10px
</style>

<script>
import UploadMediaFiles from '../atoms/UploadMediaFiles.vue'
export default {
  name: 'SelectAndPreviewFiles',
  components: {
    UploadMediaFiles,
  },
  props: {},
  data() {
    return {
      selectedFiles: [],
    }
  },
  computed: {},
  methods: {
    selectFiles(files) {
      this.selectedFiles.push(files)
      this.previewImage(files)
    },
    previewImage(files) {
      var vm = this
      for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        var reader = new FileReader()
        reader.onload = function (event) {
          const imageUrl = event.target.result
          vm.files.push(imageUrl)
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[index])
      }
    },
    deleteFile(index) {
      this.selectedFiles.splice(index, 1)
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**CodePen without the parent-child relationship**
https://codepen.io/LovelyAndy/pen/gOmYGKO?editors=0001

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error in the codepen. What files are you trying to load?

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The code pen is not the same implimentation as the code above. Unfortunately I am not understanding how to turn what I have in the single component in my codepen, into a parent to child relation implimentation. I'm trying to get both images and video files to be uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `input` value for multiple selected files is an array of `FileList`s, which itself is a list of `File` objects. However, `previewImage()` seems to assume that the value is an array of `File` objects.

`files[index]` is actually a `FileList`, which is not an acceptable argument to `reader.readAsDataURL()`, leading to the error.

To resolve the issue, iterate each `FileList` in the array:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    selectFiles(files) {
      this.selectedFiles.push(files);
      this.previewImage(files);
    },
    previewImage(files) {
      var vm = this
      for (var index = 0; index < files.length; index++) {
        const fileList = files[index]
        fileList.forEach(file => {
          var reader = new FileReader()
          reader.onload = function (event) {
            const imageUrl = event.target.result
            vm.selectedFiles.push(imageUrl)
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(file)
        })
      }
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reading-multiple-files-from-input-bu58n?file=/src/components/SelectAndPreviewFiles.vue)

Comment: Again, Tony, thank you for going through the trouble of making a demo for this. It works great on your demo, but for some reason on my end I get a `"TypeError: fileList.forEach is not a function"` error that I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction in GitHub?

Comment: Also, what is the value of `fileList` in your code?

Comment: I'm currently writing this inside of a big app I'm working on, so I'll try and figure out a way to isolate these two parts!

The value of `fileList` is `FileList {0: File, 1: File, length: 2}`. Upon opening I get the normal file break down like `0: File {name: 'something.jpg'~~~~}`

Comment: So, I made a new repo for just this small set up and as I expected, your code totally checks out on that. It must just be with the multiple libraries at use in the project I'm working with. I'll keep looking into what the issue is if I can manage it. Not sure thre's much more you can do in this regard.
Anyway though, cheers for all the help over the last couple days; you're helping a newbie like me not give up hope.
https://github.com/LovelyAndy/add-media